# Error when importing GeoJson into BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery, geojson

I'm trying to load GeoJson data [1] into BigQuery via Cloud Shell but I'm getting the following error:

`Failed to parse JSON: Top-level GeoJson 'type' member should have value 'Feature', but was 'FeatureCollection'.; ParsedString returned false; Could not parse value; Parser terminated before end of string`

It feels like the GeoJson file is not formatted properly for BQ but I have no idea if that's true or how to fix it.

[1] https://github.com/tonywr71/GeoJson-Data/blob/master/australian-suburbs.geojson

Answer (score 2):

Expounding on @scespinoza's answer, I was able to convert to new-line delimited GeoJSON and load it to Bigquery with the following steps:

1. `geojson2ndjson geodata.txt > geodata_converted.txt`
2. Using this [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#geojson-files), I encountered an error:
   [image]

   But was able to create a workaround by splitting the data into 2 tables, applying the same command.

Loaded table in Bigquery:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in standard GeoJSON format, but BigQuery only accepts new-line delimited GeoJSON files and individual GeoJSON objects (see documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#geojson-files). So, you  should first convert the dataset to the appropiated format. Here is a good and simple explanation on how it works: https://stevage.github.io/ndgeojson/.